# Overriding named template in XSLT

Tags: xslt, overriding

I have meta.xsl that contains meta data for  
I have call template:

```
<xsl:call-template name="og-type" />
```

Template is in the meta.xsl(for all pages):

```
<xsl:template name="og-type">
 <meta property="og:type" content="website"></meta>
</xsl:template>
```

The question is how to override this template, i need to use overrided template in Articles.xsl (this is just for Article page).

```
<xsl:template name="og-type">
 <meta property="og:type" content="article"></meta>
</xsl:template>
```

Yes i can put first variant of template in Mainpage.xsl, but what if it would be 10 more templates? I will get error cause it would be call to nothing.

Comment: Not sure this is a solution or not, by try putting `priority` attributes on the templates, if you can.

Comment: Not working(

compilation error: file /templates/article.xsl line 263 element template
xsl:template: error duplicate name 'og-type'

Comment: your two og-type templates are identical as posted. The answer is to a template of higher import precedence or just to define your utemplate so that rather than outputting a fixed template it outputs different templates depending on the input document (which might mean it's easier to use a matching template rather than a named one) But you give no indication of your input, so hard to say.

Comment: Update the code again, now it's like in the site.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to override the template on a static basis when your base stylesheet is imported into another, either priority or modes might be the best answer. Priority actually has an "importance" factor built into it, so the importing stylesheet's version should always be the one that's selected by default unless priority or mode overrides that choice.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

If you only want the different behavior when processing under particular conditions, it sounds like what you want is to associate the variant template with an XSLT Mode, and have logic at one of the templates above that point recognize which case is relevant and issue a call-template which switches into the appropriate mode.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes

Comment: AFAIK named templates do not have priorities, only those with `match` do:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-template